# Specify JRockit or JDK to Maven

Tags: maven, jrockit

I'd like to know how to specify the path of JRockit libraries to Maven to use , same as we do for eclipse when you specify the JRE .

Also how do i configure maven to use Sun JDK in a project and use JRockit in another project ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number of options available:

1. Maven uses the JAVA_HOME environment variable to determine which JVM
   should run Maven (Maven is itself a Java program). I recommend this as the first option because build servers like [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/) can easily control the JVM being used to run Maven.
2. You can tweak the settings of the compiler plugin to [compile using
   a different JDK](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/compile-using-different-jdk.html)
3. An alternative approach (clearer to others running your build) would
   be to build in a pre-condition check into the POM, using the
   [enforcer plug-in](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/index.html). Specify a rule that the it should be compiled
   using a [specified Java version](http://maven.apache.org/enforcer/enforcer-rules/requireJavaVersion.html).